# JavaScript function pass string argument to refer to variable withion function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```js
const dayChooser = day => {
  const Monday = [];
  const Tuesday = [];
  const Wednesday = [];
  const Thursday = [];
  const Friday = [];
  const Saturday = [];
  const Sunday = [];

  day.push("It works!");
};

dayChooser(Monday);

console.log(Monday);
```

Should show:

```
[
  "It works!"
]
```

How can I achieve this? I tried googling for some solutions but I cannot seem to find an elegant solution to this. Surely there is an easy way to do this right?

**EDIT:**
Found a solution finally:

```js
const dayChooser = day => {
  const Monday = [];
  const Tuesday = [];
  const Wednesday = [];
  const Thursday = [];
  const Friday = [];
  const Saturday = [];
  const Sunday = [];

  day = eval(day)

  day.push("It works!");
  console.log(Monday)
}

dayChooser("Monday")
```

Comment: I think that you should simply be passing the variable `Monday` instead of the string literal `"Monday"` to your `dayChooser` function call.

Comment: You can create an object with all your arrays in them and then pass the name of the array as an argument, or instead, just pass a reference to the array if it isn't dynamic

Comment: @NickParsons don't think this is a case for "variable variables". It's just confusion over how to pass a parameter which is an array.

Comment: I made a very stupid mistake in the example. I'm actually using React Native and cannto simply pass the variable Monday since the variable is declared in the function itself. Updating OP to reflect this now.

Comment: @VLAZ hm, maybe, it would depend on whether OP gets the variable name dynamically somehow

Comment: @NickParsons OK, after the update *now* it's variable variables...

Comment: @rago182 `eval` is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea). I suggest you see the second code snippet in the duplicate which involves making an object

Comment: @rago182 [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gtdn4k0f/) is how you may do it if you're using an object.